# How to monitor client information by scapy?

Tags: python, wireless, scapy

I have a question. I need to monitor client devices by using scapy. The below code will get Access point information. Is there any body can guide me how to just monitor client information and shows their information  such as signal strength, mac address and which channel.

```
def PacketHandler(pkt) :
        if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) :
                if pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 8 :
                        if pkt.addr2 not in aps :
                                aps.append(pkt.addr2)
                                print "Found BSSID %s and SSID %s " %(pkt.addr2, pkt.info)

#Begin sniffing and pass each packet to the PacketHandler function above.
sniff(iface="mon0", prn = PacketHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples:

print the packets source MAC address `pkt[0][Ether].src`

print the packets source IP address   `pkt[0][IP].src`

All the other information you want regarding Access point information could be found [here](http://www.devx.com/security/Article/34741)